# ReturnGeneratedKeys Empty Despite Successful Batch Insert

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

so I started a new project recently and have been inserting data to a MariaDB table. I've been able to get generated keys in the past, so this is a little wonky for me to see. The rows are being inserted, as I can see after refreshing my table, but no generated keys are being returned. This is my current code.

```
    try (Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items (chrid, accountid, type, pos, itemid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Equip>> equips = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Pair<Integer, Integer> item : items) {
                equips.add(itemCreationSystem.createEquip(item.right));
                ps.setInt(1, dbId.dbId);
                ps.setInt(2, client.accountId);
                ps.setInt(3, 0);
                ps.setInt(4, item.left);
                ps.setInt(5, item.right);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                try (PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO equips (itemKey, slots, successfulUpgrades, str, dex, intel, luk, hp, mp, " +
                                "wAtk, mAtk, wDef, mDef, equipPos)")) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Pair<Integer, Equip> pair = equips.remove(0);
                        Equip equip = pair.right;
                            ps2.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
                            ps2.setShort(2, equip.upgradeSlots);
                            ps2.setShort(3, equip.successfulUpgrades);
                            ps2.setShort(4, equip.getProperty("STR"));
                            ps2.setShort(5, equip.getProperty("DEX"));
                            ps2.setShort(6, equip.getProperty("INT"));
                            ps2.setShort(7, equip.getProperty("INT"));
                            ps2.setShort(8, equip.getProperty("HP"));
                            ps2.setShort(9, equip.getProperty("MMP"));
                            ps2.setShort(10, equip.getProperty("PAD"));
                            ps2.setShort(11, equip.getProperty("MAD"));
                            ps2.setShort(12, equip.getProperty("PDD"));
                            ps2.setShort(13, equip.getProperty("MDD"));
                            ps2.setInt(14, pair.left);
                            ps2.addBatch();
                    }
                    ps2.executeBatch();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've been toying with autoCommit, but haven't gotten any results. I suspect maybe that's it, but unless I commit it to true there or after the query, no rows will get inserted.

Comment: Could you indicate server version and driver version  and DDL of this items table ? items table must have identifier with AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Table has AUTO_INCREMENT and id is listed as a primary key. I'm not sure what you mean by DDL. Server is 10.1.31-MariaDB - Source distribution. Driver version is 1.2.0 org.mariadb.jdbc.

Comment: Oh shoot I got suspicious of the driver version and went to maven to update to the latest jdbc driver. It works now!